# Convert via terminal CRW format to JPG or PNG

Tags: 12.04, image-processing, conversion

How can I convert CRW format images to JPG or PNG via terminal. tried `convert` and `mogrify` with no luck. It gave a weird corrupted error while processing the CRW files but I can view them fine using Shotwell for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagemagick, according to http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php, supports CRW (Canon Raw Image Format), which as such should work with `convert`.

```
convert source.crw target.jpg
```

If this does not work there are two possibilities:

1. Your source image is corrupted
2. Imagemagicks support of crw is flawed,

in which case you should report a bug at http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/.

Comment: you are correct. It is flawed. I will report the bug thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "ufraw" should allow you to convert them with a GUI or via command line with the ufraw-batch command.